# Expression.ToString() with format provider

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

Is it possible to convert a lambda expression like `x => x + 1.5` to string using specific culture/format options? I know I can do:

```
Expression<Func<double,double>> expr = x => x + 1.5;
string s = expr.Body.ToString();
```

But with some app language settings it gives `s` equal to `"x + 1,5"` (with a comma instead of a dot). It seems that ToString() takes current culture info.

How to get back the string in its original form, culture-invariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but it's really ugly... just change the current culture temporarily:

```
var previousCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
try
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    Expression<Func<double,double>> expr = x => x + 1.5;
    string s = expr.Body.ToString();
}
finally
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = previousCulture;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? `string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0}", expr.Body)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I ask what is the `try` block for in this case? Where do you expect an exception to occur?

Comment: @rook, actually in this case it's not really useful, but when I temporarily change global state (such as the current culture), I want to make sure I put it back the way it was, should anything happen. A finally block is a good way to ensure that.

Comment: @SebastianPiu, this works only if the formatted type implements IFormattable